# eclipse(oxygen-latest) brings error after connecting ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, ddms

After Connecting ADT eclipse brings window like this[First Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dogWE.png)
After clicking **Open SDK Manager**
It is starting to load SDK
But nothing happpen
And eclipse brings error[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz28D.png)

Please help me I have probles with eclipse approximatley 4 mounth

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) is the current stable release of Eclipse. However Eclipse has not been officially supported for Android development for quite some time now.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok thank you very much but now I'm trying same on eclipse mars but it again brings error